# Add a micro table on top of larger table

Tags: powershell

I have a script that generates a license report and emails the report.

Recently I was asked if a micro table of the base numbers can be added to the top of the larger report. I can make what I want in a spreadsheet program but not with powershell so far.

What I want is the report title then

```
TotalMain             = <A number>
NewMainInUse          = <A number>
NewTotalRemainMain    = <A number>
TotalArchive          = <A number>     (<-------MICRO TABLE)
NewArchiveInUse       = <A number>
NewTotalRemainArchive = <A number>
NewShouldBeArchive    = <A number>
#a space then columns like the the following with the related data below  
Email|Type|LastUsed|TotalMain|MainInUse|TotalRemainMain|TotalArchive|ArchiveInUse (<--Main table)
emailaddress|license type|date|number|number|number|number|number
emailaddress|license type|date|number|number|number|number|number
emailaddress|license type|date|number|number|number|number|number
etc
```

here is a screen shot
[image]

I thought the code would be like the following. This worked before I tried to insert the micro table

```
 Add-Content -Path .\$Filename -Value "here is a test" 
 $FinalResults | Export-Csv .\$Filename -NoTypeInformation -Append -force
```

Once I do this the csv has "here is a test" and lots of blank lines.
How do i insert the micro table data ?

Comment: What is a "micro table"? Can you share a screenshot of one created in a spreadsheet perhaps?

Comment: okay i will get one and amend. hang on @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen done

Comment: I do understand that the micro table has the same data as the larger table but slimmed.
Some of my audience wants a quick summary and some want all the detail

Comment: CSV is a plain text format, I assume by _micro table_ you refer to Excel's _Micro Chart_, if that's the case, what you want is not possible with a CSV.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I added a screen shot of what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: You might be able to achieve that using the `ImportExcel` module but I'm unsure

Comment: I can't just insert the lines at the top of the csv then export the array below the lines? 
@SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: @dcaz it won't be a CSV if you do that. The format is quite basic and limited to a single table with the same number of columns in every row. You might find Doug Finke's [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.0.1) module useful for creating more complex Excel spreadsheets, that has a link to a YouTube series where he introduces it. But it won't be as simple as export-csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my understanding of a csv and exporting to csv was incomplete.

A csv is meant for a string https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-1

I can do as I need with imprt-excel https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

I will update with code after I get a chance to add it.